# Is there any way to prevent content jumping after giving body element overflow-y with js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am using javascript to open a menu and in the same time I am giving the body element overflow-y to prevent scrolling while the menu is open.The issue I have is that the content jumps because the scroll bar is removed temporary.Is there any to prevent it from happening?

Comment: you can add padding to the right side. But be aware that different browsers have different scrollbars. Some of scrollbars even don't have width and only appear when user scroll a page